# How to do an AJAX call in an MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor view with an AJAX call and it skips right over it. I have a debug break point on the controller method. I never gets there. Also, the Alert iin startup script does not even get executed.

I tried moving the script before the 1st paragraph in the case. No change.

View code:

It goes into the switch statement - the "New" case, but does not do the Ajax call. In debug, it hits @Session["UserName"] then goes to the break.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@switch (@Session["NavState"])
{
case "New":
    <br />
    <p>Hi <span class="username">@Session["UserName"]</span> !</p>
    <br />
    <p> I'm so glad you decided to join us. Feel free to look around.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.post("UserProfile/SetSessionVar", { variable = "NavState" }, function () { });
    </script>

    break;
case "Exists":
    <br />
    <p>Welcome back <span class="username">@Session["UserName"]</span> !</p>
    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.post("UserProfile/SetSessionVar", { variable = "NavState" }, function () { });
    </script>

    break;
default:
    break;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    Alert("here");
});
</script>
```

I tried changing the $.post to a $.ajax. No change.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetSessionVar() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserProfile/SetSessionVar",
                data: '{variable: "NavState"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
    </script>
```

Controller method:

```
    public void SetSessionVar(string variable)
    {
        if (variable == "NavState")
        {
            Session["NavState"] = "x";
        }
    }
```

Bundle.config:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace GbngWebClient
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(                                                                
                                     "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(                                                                
                                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(                                                                
                                     "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(                                                                
                                     "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(                                                              
                                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",                                                              
                                    "~/Content/site.css",                                                              
                                    "~/Content/validation.css"));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does the JS render? What does your browser console show? Does your jquery bundler render correctly?

Comment: I keep forgetting to check the console. After doing so, I see that the startup alert code was failing because it was capital A instead of lowercase a. So now the JS is recognized. Then my $.post was not syntactically correct. I fixed it. So all is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startup alert code was failing because it was capital A instead of lowercase a. Then my $.post was not syntactically correct. Should be: $.post("UserProfile/SetSessionVar", { variable: "NavState" });

Answer (score 0):

```
var SetSessionVar = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/UserProfile/SetSessionVar",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
             data: '{variable: "NavState"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
            }
            else {
                alert("failed");
            }
        }

    })
}
```